# CakePHP: Best practices for associating small, "choice" tables

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-model

quick best-practices question(s).

I have as association as follows:
User hasOne UserBasicInfo
UserBasicInfo has a select element for country (in which the user is living).
The select element is populated by a simple 'countries' table (id, country name, abbreviation)

Is it best to use Model::query() for getting the data from the countries table?  Or should I create a model for this data?

If creating a model, should I use an association with the UserBasicInfo model, Or should I just use the $uses variable?

If it sways the answer, there are actually many select fields populated in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it sways the answer, there are actually many select fields populated in a similar fashion.

It might. Do you have multiple Country select boxes, or are these select fields all pulling from different tables? If the former, you can use the `options` key in [`FormHelper::select()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aselect) to populate multiple selects from one array:

#### Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Country');
$this->set('countries', $this->Country->find('list'));
```

#### View:

```
$this->Form->select('UserBillingInfo.country_id', $countries);
$this->Form->select('UserShippingInfo.country_id', $countries);
etc...
```

---

Otherwise, I typically handle this situation by creating the proper associations between my models, and then using either `Model::find('list')` or a custom Model method to retrieve the options. If you name your variables properly, the options variable will automatically be used as the options for your select:

#### Controller:

```
$this->set('countries', $this->User->UserBasicInfo->Country->find('list'));
```

#### View:

```
$this->Form->input('UserBasicInfo.country_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Model::query() is never best for doing anything in cakephp.

in the UsersController action you are using

```
$this->set('countries', $this->User->Country->find('list'));
```

in the edit / add form

```
$this->Form->input('country_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use view helper for this kind of select elements. If I take your case as an example, I'd do in this way:

controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
      ....
      public $helpers = array('Common');
      ....
}
```

helper:

```
class CommonHelper extends AppHelper {
      ....
      public function get_country_list() {
            App::import( 'Model', 'Country' );
            $objCountry = new Country();
            $countries = $objCountry->find( 'list' );
            return $countries;
      }
      ....
}
```

view:

```
....
echo $this->Form->input('country_id', array(
     'options' => $this->Common->get_country_list(),
     'value' => !empty($data['UserBasicInfo']['country_id']) ? $data['UserBasicInfo']['country_id'] : ''
));
....
```

The condition is that **you must have a Country model**. In this way you can populate any drop-down menu. Cheers!!!

Comment: That's violating the MVC pattern.

Comment: Excuse me, can u give me a hint as to how it violates the MVC pattern? And also what is purpose of Helper then?

Comment: Read the book, it has a section about MVC and Helpers -> book.cakephp.org. App::import() is s as well wrong here and instantiating models directly is a no go as well.

Comment: Thanks burzum for pointing me out that. I always prefer to follow the best practices. I'll change my way of coding as I mentioned above here.